# maven-dependency-plugin: exclude .jar files

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, maven-dependency-plugin

I am using maven-dependency-plugin. I need to download only a ZIP file and exclude all jar files.

Plugin configuration looks the following way.

```xml
<execution>
    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <!-- <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory> -->
        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
        <excludes>**/*.jar</excludes>
        <includes>**/*.zip</includes>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

The plugin still downloads everything: all jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`copy-dependencies`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) goal of the `maven-dependency-plugin` does not support `includes` and `excludes` attributes.

However, you can use the [`excludeTypes`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#excludeTypes) attributes to exclude specific [types of dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates).

> Comma Separated list of Types to exclude. Empty String indicates don't exclude anything (default).

The following will exclude all the `jar` dependencies:

```xml
<execution>
    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <!-- <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory> -->
        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
        <excludeTypes>jar</excludeTypes>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: It still copies all dependencies. The maven command I run is "clean package dependency:copy-dependencies -PdownloadIosAgents,x64 -X"

Comment: @Michael The problem is because you are invoking `dependency:copy-dependencies` explicitely but we configured a specific execution. Long story short: `clean package -PdownloadIosAgents,x64 -X` is what you should execute :)

Comment: the starnge thing is that all JAR's were excluded except for one - "util-master-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar". And I cannot figure out why.

Comment: @Michael Hmm, is that one generated by your project? Could you make a gist (or other) of your Maven log with debug enabled `-X`?