# How to copy only OS specific dependency jars by Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm currently working on a project that uses (among others) nd4j, deeplearning4j dependencies. These dependencies include versions for different OS, like "nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta6-android-arm.jar" or "nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta6-linux-armhf.jar" etc.

As the project will only run on linux-x64, I'm wondering whether there's a way to tell Maven to *not* copy the JARs that are not needed. I hope to reduce the required disk space needed by unnecessary libs.

The pom.xml currently looks like this to be able to produce a deployable output:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.clerezza.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.json.simple</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.kohlschutter.junixsocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>junixsocket-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.kohlschutter.junixsocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>junixsocket-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-parallel-wrapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
                            <useRepositoryLayout>true</useRepositoryLayout>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathLayoutType>repository</classpathLayoutType>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>MyMainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Hmhm, I just found this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34839656/2086717. Seems to be similar but the answer is not what I was looking for. The proposed filter mechanism by the topic creator though is what would be nice to have if there's no other way to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 4):

Generally if you want to bundle platform specific binaries for dl4j or anything based on javacpp, you can do the following:
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Reducing-the-Number-of-Dependencies

Concretely, you would just specify -Djavacpp.platform=linux-x86_64 for all javacpp dependencies.

Comment: This might be the solution I'm looking for! :-D One further question: I'm trying to put that setting into my pom.xml, but if I add <javacpp.platform>linux-x86-64</platform> into the <properties>...</properties> section, it won't work. If I add the -D... option to the command line, it works ...

Comment: I added an issue over at the JavaCPP GitHub (https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/issues/846), as I'm currently not 100% sure where the -D / <properties> issue acutally lies.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `<exclusions>` on dependencies:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

An example would be:

```xml
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.something</groupId>
      <artifactId>some-jar</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  
          <groupId>de.dumm</groupId>
          <artifactId>nicht-benutzen</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```

Comment: But I can only exclude whole dependencies by this and not JARs that are part of a depency, right?

Comment: Usually, dependencies don't "include" other dependencies, but reference them in their POM. Maven resolves everything transitively.

Comment: Generally I wouldn't recommend this approach for classifiers. This is mainly for artifact ids.